# asp.net mvc regular expression phone

Tags: asp.net-mvc, regex

```
  [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9_,:- ]*", ErrorMessage = "Phone can Contains only Only Alphanumeric Characters ")]
```

How can I validate accomodate () ' in the above regular expression, it is giving a parsing error.

Answer (score 0):

try `^[a-zA-Z0-9_,: -]*`

the hyphen needs to be at the end of the set, otherwise it's considered a range, in this case a range from `:` (ascii 58) to space (ascii 32). flip that part and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

Try for "000-000-0000" format

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$", ErrorMessage = "Entered phone format is not valid.")]
```